# What is "Memory Management" in iOS?

Tags: ios, memory-management

I have been given these 2 questions in my interview.

```
1. What is **MEMORY MANAGEMENT** in iOS.

2. What is reference counting?
```

Can any one explain this to me? I am new to iOS. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this really off topic though? It appears to be a programmer legitimately trying to understand the concept of memory management/arc. Though its someone basic concept, I think closing it off topic is not the write close reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application memory management is the process of allocating memory during your program’s runtime, using it, and freeing it when you are done with it. A well-written program uses as little memory as possible. In Objective-C, it can also be seen as a way of distributing ownership of limited memory resources among many pieces of data and code. When you have finished working through this guide, you will have the knowledge you need to manage your application’s memory by explicitly managing the life cycle of objects and freeing them when they are no longer needed.

[Reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but about memory management (like how to deliver that answer about memory management to others) can you explain little bit more

Answer (score 1):

Memory management is important to development of any type. Mobile devices in general have less memory to work with than full sized computers, and so it is even more critical that you manage memory wisely when working with them. This means ensuring that you do not hold on to memory any longer than you need to, and that you are careful about the amount of memory that you allocate.

Luckily in iOS it is no longer necessary to deal directly with reference counting because it is handled automatically by ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), but it is still good to know what it is. Whenever an object is allocated it gets a reference count of 1. That reference count can be increased by calling retain, or decreased by calling release. When the reference count hits 0, the object is deallocated.

Comment: Memory management is not unique to mobile devices, though.

Comment: Certainly not. Just emphasized by the restricted resources available.
I edited my answer to make it more clear.